# PostSharp - args.ReturnValye = default(T) -> T = method return type, how?

Tags: return-type, postsharp

My aspect:

```
 [Serializable]
class FlowController : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static bool logging;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (logging)
            return;

        try
        {
            logging = true;
            if (ProgramState.State() == false)
            {
                args.ReturnValue = ""; // WHAT DO I SET HERE?
                args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            logging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the ProgramState.State() method checks if the program is running(true),paused(loops while isPaused == true), stopped(false), this should control the if methods can run or not(basically a start pause/resume stop thing)

But sometimes i get nullreferences when returning from the method.

i am interested in knowing how can i set the return type to the default return type of the method.

Answer (score 2):

It is tested with PostSharp 6.0.29

Before use it please check required null controls.
If method is async Task

```
 public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var methodReturnType = ((System.Reflection.MethodInfo)args.Method).ReturnType;
        var runtime = methodReturnType.GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("m_result"));

        //Only if return type has parameterless constructture (should be check before create)
        var returnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(runtime.FieldType);

        args.ReturnValue = returnValue;
    }
```

And if method is not async

```
 public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var methodReturnType = ((System.Reflection.MethodInfo)args.Method).ReturnType;

        //Only if return type has parameterless constructture (should be check before create)
        var returnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(methodReturnType);

        args.ReturnValue = returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your aspect class generic with the generic parameter representing the method return type. Then you need to create a method-level attribute that is also an aspect provider. The attribute will be applied to the user code and in turn it can provide the correct instance of the generic aspect.

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage( MulticastTargets.Method )]
public class FlowControllerAttribute : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo) targetElement;

        Type returnType = method.ReturnType == typeof(void)
            ? typeof(object)
            : method.ReturnType;

        IAspect aspect = (IAspect) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FlowControllerAspect<>).MakeGenericType(returnType));

        yield return new AspectInstance(targetElement, aspect);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class FlowControllerAspect<T> : IOnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
    {
    }

    public void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        args.ReturnValue = default(T);
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    }

    public void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
    }
}

// Usage:
[FlowController]
public int Method()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but... Won't default(T) return nulls also?

Comment: Well, default(T) is the "zero" value for the given type T, e.g. null for reference types, 0 for ints, etc. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx